# Mp4Aar audio recorded by iOS using plugin NightlyRecorderService doesn't play on Android

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, media-player

I'm using plugin [NightlyRecorderService](https://github.com/nightlybuilds-net/nightly.xam.audiorecorder) to record voice on Xamarin Forms Android and iOS, and both seems to work as expected until you need to play the file recorded by iOS on Android(inverse works properly). I'm using [SimpleAudioPlayer](https://github.com/adrianstevens/Xamarin-Plugins/tree/master/SimpleAudioPlayer) to play the recorded audio.

Recording code:

```
//initializing the plugin using Mp4Aar and Samplig rate of 24k

NightlyRecorderService Rec = new NightlyRecorderService(new RecorderSettings
{
    DroidRecorderSettings = new DroidMp4Aar() { SamplingRate = 24000 },
    IosRecorderSettings = new IosMp4Aar() { SampleRate = 24000 },
});


// assuming we have mic/storage permissions(I have it on my real project), let's record an audio of 5 secs

Stream audioStream = await Rec.RecordAsync();

//After 5 secs
Rec.Stop();


//save the audio stream to a temp file, then upload it to file server:

string audioTemp = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string localPath = Path.Combine(audioTemp, "audioTemp");

using (FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(localPath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
{
    try
    {
        ReadWriteStream(audioStream, writeStream);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (File.Exists(localPath))
            await Task.Run(() => UploadFile("upload.php", localPath));

        writeStream.Dispose();
    }
}

private void ReadWriteStream(Stream readStream, Stream writeStream)
{
    int Length = 256;
    Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
    readStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
    // write the required bytes
    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
    }
    readStream.Close();
    writeStream.Close();
}
```

Playing code:

```
//assuming the upload was a success and we have the url to the file at fileserver: 

try
{
    Stream AudioStream = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://....audio.mp4");
        System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultCachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.CacheIfAvailable);
        return webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
    });

    if (AudioStream != null)
    {
        Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.ISimpleAudioPlayer player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer();
        if (await player.Load(AudioStream))
            player.Play();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Erro ao tentar carregar audio da internet ===>" + e.Message);
    // #1 we are falling here 
}
```

Exception/message by player.Load():

```
#1 Exception message: "Prepare failed.: status=0x1"

Console output:

[MediaPlayer] getDuration_l
[MediaPlayer] Attempt to call getDuration in wrong state: mPlayer=0x70e0901680, mCurrentState=0
[MediaPlayer] message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
[MediaPlayer] error (-38, 0)
[MediaPlayer] callback application
[MediaPlayer] back from callback
[MediaPlayer-JNI] getDuration: 0 (msec)
```

Tested on Android 7, Android 11, iOS 14.4.1

Current behavior:

If recorded by Android -> Plays on Android and iOS

If recorded by iOS -> Only plays on iOS

[Two samples of recorded audio by android and ios](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3e1b8390a483db390bf1cda87f7ff2ab20210413233401/0f6f85). Not even quicktime is able to play audio recorded by iOS.

Comment: have you opened an issue with the library's author?  Have you tried the different options for IosRecorderSettings?

Comment: @Jason  I have talk to library's author by Telegram app, but he seems to be without too much time to look into this right now. And since the library is very new I thought the chances of someone read the issue would be very small. So I decided ask here and send this question link to the author for encourage him to get in the discussion.

Comment: same issue here

Comment: I download the video and try to play it. But I was failed to play it on windows and iPhone. At first, I thought that might be because the media file was not a local file, some people met the problems because they use a remote file to play like you. But as I download it I still can not play it while the android plays well on both Windows and iPhone.

Comment: @Steven its audio only, not video... but the strange is the same plugin, same code, same app can play it on the origin phone that recorded the audio.

Comment: I just opened an issue on git as suggested by @Jason https://github.com/nightlybuilds-net/nightly.xam.audiorecorder/issues/4

Comment: @Jason have tried with others IosRecorderSettings but same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem on iOS, changing NightlyRecorderService by
Plugin.AudioRecorder. When the audio is recorded, I convert it to m4u, what allows to achieve a lightweight audio file and be reproduced in any device.

As this solution uses iOS specific code, I opted by to create an interface:

IConvertAudioFile.cs in Shared Project:

```
public interface IConvertAudioFile
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> ConvertAudioFile(Plugin.AudioRecorder.AudioRecorderService gravadorIos);
}
```

RecordAudio.cs in Shared Project:

```
// instantiate the recorder according to your needs:

static AudioRecorderService gravadorIos = new AudioRecorderService()
{
   StopRecordingOnSilence = false,
   SilenceThreshold = 0,
   PreferredSampleRate = 24000
};

// the code that is called when you click to stop recording:

if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
{
    await gravadorIos.StopRecording();
    _ = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            string filePath2Upload = await DependencyService.Get<IConvertAudioFile>().ConvertAudioFile(gravadorIos);
            ShareAudio(filePath2Upload);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            #if DEBUG
            Console.WriteLine("++++++++ ERROR WHILE EXPORTING " + err.Message);
            #endif
        }
    });
}
```

IConvertAudioFile in iOS Project:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ThisApp.iOS;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ConvertAudioService))]
namespace ThisApp.iOS
{
    public class ConvertAudioService : IConvertAudioFile
    {
        public async Task<string> ConvertAudioFile(Plugin.AudioRecorder.AudioRecorderService gravadorIos)
        {
            var asset = AVFoundation.AVAsset.FromUrl(Foundation.NSUrl.FromFilename(gravadorIos.GetAudioFilePath()));
            var export = new AVFoundation.AVAssetExportSession(asset, AVFoundation.AVAssetExportSession.PresetAppleM4A);

            string u = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "temp_last_audio.m4a");
            if (File.Exists(u))
                File.Delete(u);

            export.OutputUrl = Foundation.NSUrl.FromFilename(u);
            export.OutputFileType = AVFoundation.AVFileType.AppleM4A;
            export.ShouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true;

            string returnString="";

            await export.ExportTaskAsync();
                        
            if (export.Error != null)
            {
                #if DEBUG
                Console.WriteLine("++++++++ ERROR WHILE EXPORTING WAV TO MP4: LETS USE WAV INSTEAD");
                #endif
                returnString = gravadorIos.GetAudioFilePath();
            }
            else
            {
                #if DEBUG
                Console.WriteLine("++++++++ SUCCESS EXPORTED WAV TO MP4");
                #endif
                returnString = u;
            }

            return returnString;
        }
    }
}
```